# How do I add a border multiple cells at a time in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating an iOS app with Swift where I have a tableView with multiple cells. I want a tableView where each set of three cells have a border and there is a small gap between each set three cells.
This is what each cell looks like in the tableView.

[image: each cell in the table view]

I would like to combine the shadow effect/border for the three cells so that it looks like a single entity. The next cell would be part of a new set of three cells.

I would like to do this because many apps display tableViews like what I mentioned above. For example Flipkart displays a tableView with three cells under "Music" with each cell containing a headphone and after a small gap displays "Shoes" with three shoes occupying each cell. 
How do I get a similar effect?

Comment: If you can share the screenshot of what you desire then it would make answering the question easier. However, you can use multiple sections in your tableview so that each section contains only these three cells. Use section headers to separate the sections.

Comment: You create your own custom cell by subclassing UITableViewCell. There are tutorials out there just try googling "custom UITableviewCell".

Comment: is that the main [output](https://s22.postimg.org/tqm5jux29/Screen_Shot_2016_10_09_at_1_37_14_PM.png) you want to get? I am asking to make sure because the answer will take a long time to be described :D

Comment: This is what it currently looks like. Will post a screenshot of what I want it to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar in my app. The approach I used was to put a UICollectionView inside each table view cell. There is an excellent tutorial on how to do exactly this.

*Putting a UICollectionView in a UITableViewCell in Swift:
https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/*

This should work for you with a few modifications:

In the example, he has a horizontally scrolling collection view. You will want a vertical collection view, with collection view cells that cover the entire width of the table view cell. The best way to do this will most likely be to select both the table view cell and the collection view in the storyboard and add a constraint "Equal Widths".

You will also want to set the height of your table view cell to be equal to the height of the entire collection view. If you will always have exactly 3 items in your collection view of fixed height, then you can simply hardcode the height of your table view cell. However, if the number of items in the collection view will change for different table view cells, then you will want to add a constraint for "Equal Heights", similarly to as I have described in the previous step.

It should be noted that since your content will be displayed vertically, you could achieve the same result by adding a UITableView (instead of a UICollectionView) to each TableView cell, but this adds some complications because both table views will be calling the same methods in your ViewController.swift file. The workaround is to use tags to identify which table view is calling the method, but I personally think it is more straightforward to have a UITableView be your parent, and a UICollectionView to be your child.

Feel free to post a comment you require any elaboration :)

Comment: Great. I will try it out and let you know.